# Is it possible to have icons on Action Bar Tabs for Android?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-actionbar, android-tabs

Is it possible to have icons on Action Bar Tabs for Android?

If so, can someone point me to an example of someone who's accomplished it?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Checkout this link [`ActionBar.Tab.setIcon(Drawable)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActionBar.Tab.html#setIcon%28android.graphics.drawable.Drawable%29)
Sample code

```
tab = getActionBar.newTab();
tab.setText(tabText);
tab.setIcon(R.drawable.tab_icon);
```

Comment: can set selected icon too?

Comment: Try creating xml state list drawable and set it as an icon. Here is the [link to documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#StateList)

Comment: for future reference, the state you need to use is "state_selected"